How to get nginx server metrics with labels
I have an nginx deployed as a daemon set on my k8s cluster. I want to get the prometheus metrics for the server.
Is there a way to get route specific metrics??
For eg:
I my nginx conf i have these routes defined:
location /prometheus {
  auth_basic "Restricted Access";  # Displayed in the authentication prompt
  auth_basic_user_file /auth/htpasswd;  # Path to the password file
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9098;
}

location /api/gms/ {
  proxy_pass https://main-os-nginx;
  proxy_set_header site REPLACE_WITH_SITE_NAME;
  proxy_set_header company REPLACE_WITH_COMPANY_NAME;
  proxy_set_header node REPLACE_WITH_NODE_NAME;
}

So i want to get how many requests were sent to the route "/prometheus" & how many were sent to "/api/gms/".
I saw we have nginx-prometheus-exporter, but it just exposes very basic stub_status metrics for nginx server, here and that too without any labels.

Consider to ask sys-admin questions (e.g. about configuring monitoring) on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.
